# Using WeakEventManager, hiding the actual event

Tags: c#, .net

When using the `WeakEventManager`, it is apparent that the event is hooked up to the `AddHandler` using reflection (from `nameof()` in example). The `AddHandler` does NOT work if the event is private or protected. I'd prefer to not expose the event and force the consumers to use the `Subscribe` events.  I could use a private class to hold the events.

```
 public static event EventHandler<IntensityChangedEventArgs> OnIntensityChanged;

    public static void Subscribe_OnIntensityChanged(EventHandler<IntensityChangedEventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        WeakEventManager<ADAHelper, IntensityChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(instance, nameof(ADAHelper.OnIntensityChanged), eventHandler);
    }
```

This works but the problem is that the

`public static event EventHandler<IntensityChangedEventArgs> OnIntensityChanged;`
 is public exposed.  This needs to be private so that consumers of the event can't subscribe to it directl (which causes the problem this fixes) I want to force them to Subscribe_OnIntensityChanged method.

A one-off private class would work, a re-usable generic would be great.

How do I create a wrapper class (for the event) to hide the event from public (or internal) usage?

Comment: Although I can't make any sense of the question, maybe this is one of the cases where `internal` would be useful?

Comment: To clarify, if another class subscribes directly to OnIntensityChanged event, it will result in a memory leak (because it is static) unless the developer is careful to unhook the event.  Forcing the developer to use the Subscribe_OnIntenstityChanged solves the problem.  However, in this example the opportunity to use the OnIntensityChange is still there.  Better to leave the implementor to only have one, correct choice.

Comment: Note that with your proposed design you've actually prevented the user of this type from unsubscribing events.

Comment: Writing one-off private classes are really the only way I know of to solve this, unless you start delving in to [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) (ex: [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) or [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody)) to do the writing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a private class. I did try the generic route for a bit but the syntax and clarity of the solution was less than ideal.  Private class is probably better as you only need one private class that could then hold many events.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// wrapper to keep from exposing the actual event. Want to force them to subscribe weakly
    /// </summary>
    private OnIntensityChangedEventWrapper onIntensityChangedEventWrapper = new ADAHelper.OnIntensityChangedEventWrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Event notifying when the intensity has changed. This event will only fire when the ADA button was pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Subscribe_OnIntensityChanged(EventHandler<IntensityChangedEventArgs> eventHandler)
    {
        WeakEventManager<OnIntensityChangedEventWrapper, IntensityChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(Instance.onIntensityChangedEventWrapper, nameof(OnIntensityChangedEventWrapper.OnIntensityChanged), eventHandler);
    }

    private class OnIntensityChangedEventWrapper
    {
        public event EventHandler<IntensityChangedEventArgs> OnIntensityChanged;

        public void Fire(Intensity intensity)
        {
            if (OnIntensityChanged != null)
            {
                OnIntensityChanged(this, new IntensityChangedEventArgs(intensity));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Leandro, good suggestion, now where were you a couple of days ago. ;)

Comment: @LeandroTaset what do you mean exactly? Add/remove cannot have access modifiers and if you were to use the add/remove methods, you could not fire the event unless you would add private backing field and fire that ...which brings us to the original problem, cannot add private events.

Comment: @Leandro Not really a private event like OP asked (the event is public!), but ended up using pretty much same code. Two public events, one fake: `public event OnEvent { add {WeakEventManager.Register(nameof(OnEventDONOTUSE)) } }` and the required public backing field `public event OnEventDONOTUSE` using the name itself rather than access modifier. Anyhow, kind of dumb design of API.

Comment: @Leandro I was legitely curious if I was missing something, if the add/remove can be used to hide the event from user. Short answer is: "It cannot, it does not solve OP's problem (but its cooler syntax)". The confusion here is from that your comment can be understood as either *alternative solution* or *wrapping existing solution* methods in cooler syntax. This is why it is on SO advised not-to give one sentence answers/comments and provide more context.