# Using WeakEventManager, hiding the actual event - revisited

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have an event that should only be subscribed to using the `WeakEventManager` (for ViewModels that cannot unregister, because they have no reliable unload/dispose mechanism) and I would like to hide the original event to prevent others from using `+=`.

One problem is that the event that the `WeakEventManager` subscribes to must be public, i.e. *not hidden*. This post ([Using WeakEventManager, hiding the actual event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030047/using-weakeventmanager-hiding-the-actual-event/34090457#34090457)) has an interesting solution, where the event is wrapped in a private class (with a public event).

I adopted that solution and came up with the following helper class:

```
public class WeakEvent<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private class InternalWrapper
    {
        public event EventHandler<TEventArgs> InternalEvent;
        public void Invoke(object sender, TEventArgs args) => InternalEvent?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }

    private InternalWrapper _wrapper = new InternalWrapper();

    public void Subscribe(EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler)
    {
        WeakEventManager<InternalWrapper, TEventArgs>.AddHandler(_wrapper, nameof(InternalWrapper.InternalEvent), handler);
    }

    public void Invoke(object sender, TEventArgs args) => _wrapper.Invoke(sender, args);
}
```

My problem is: the events can be fired, but within `InternalWrapper.Invoke` the `InternalEvent` always has a `null` invocation list - as if the registration created by `WeakEventManager` was garbage collected, although `handler` is a method of a very alive instance.

Could it be the generics?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: no, it's not the generics.

Event handlers registered using the `WeakEventManager` are only triggered, if the `source` specified during registration is the same as the one used for invoking the event, i.e. it must be invoked (from the `source`) using `InternalEvent.Invoke(**this**, args)`.

One consequence of this is that the sender will always be an instance of the private internal class that is practically useless for any consuming code.

For my final implementation, below, I added an overload `Subscribe(Action<TEventArgs> action)` to keep consuming code clean, if possible. (The method returns `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` that can be used for a call to `Unsubscribe`, if required.)

**EDIT:**
When using the `Action` overload, if a reference to the returned `EventHandler` is not stored, the garbage collection will - sooner or later - collect the registration and the action will fire as expected.

Another thing to consider is that the event can be triggered/raised from any code using `public void Invoke`, but I often need and implement such a method anyway.

I find this code a lot more straight-forward and easy to use than the "native" `WeakEventManager` implementation - and, most importantly, it prevents consuming code from creating memory leaks by using `+=` to listen to the event.

```
public class WeakEvent<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private class WeakEventInternal
    {
        public event EventHandler<TEventArgs> InternalEvent;
        public void Invoke(TEventArgs args) => InternalEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    private readonly WeakEventInternal _internal= new WeakEventInternal();

    public void Subscribe(EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler) => WeakEventManager<WeakEventInternal, TEventArgs>.AddHandler(_internal, nameof(WeakEventInternal.InternalEvent), handler);

    public void Unsubscribe(EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler) => WeakEventManager<WeakEventInternal, TEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(_internal, nameof(WeakEventInternal.InternalEvent), handler);

    public EventHandler<TEventArgs> Subscribe(Action<TEventArgs> handler)
    {
        EventHandler<TEventArgs> internalHandler = (object s, TEventArgs ee) => handler(ee);

        WeakEventManager<WeakEventInternal, TEventArgs>.AddHandler(_internal, nameof(WeakEventInternal.InternalEvent), internalHandler);

        return internalHandler;
    }

    public void Invoke(TEventArgs args) => _internal.Invoke(args);
}
```

Comment: thanks, of course, to jeff (user:59546) for the original implementation!